# <span>に対するborder指定

Tags: jquery

初めまして、HTML・CSS・jQueryを勉強中の者です。
初心者向けのjQueryの勉強サイトを閲覧していて、腑に落ちない部分がありましたので、質問させて頂きます。
[image: 画像1]

質問は、こちらの画像のソースコードについてです。
実行するとspanタグで囲まれた部分が赤字になると書いてあるのですが、このソースコードだと、"spanタグで囲まれたテキストを囲う線が#c00カラーになる"という結果になりませんか？
テキストが赤字に変化するのなら、CSSセレクタの中身が('color','red');である必要があると思うのですが…どうしても腑に落ちないので、よろしければ回答お願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

当該の記事は [jQueryの$(this)の使い方(どこを指してるのか？)](http://www.flatflag.nir87.com/this-1371) でしょうか。

たしかに当該記事には

- 「クリックした`<p>`要素だけ文字色を赤字にする」
- 「クリックした`<p>`の親要素を罫線で囲う」

のようなサンプルが掲載されている中、当該コードについてはご指摘のように「クリックした`<p>`の子要素の`<span>`の罫線を〜」であり、コメントに誤りがあるようです。
基本的な理解はあっていると思うので、そういったことは元記事のコメント欄等へ投げるのが筋では。

---

一応質問文の気になった点で言えば

> CSSセレクタの中身が

CSS**セレクタ**ではありません。言うなればcssメソッドです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
そちらのサイトです！どうしても分からなかったので本当に助かりました。とてもスッキリしました。
こういった記事に対する疑問は、今度から元記事のコメント欄等へ投げることにします。すみません、CSSセレクタではなくCSSメソッドでしたね…ご指摘ありがとうございました。